# 3d projector not working properly when facing -z

Tags: javascript, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D projection script using pure JavaScript. This one mostly works but gets very warped when facing `-z`

```
let player = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
    hor: 0,
    ver: 0,
    speed: 0.1,
    move: function (dir) {
        player.x += Math.sin(dir * (Math.PI / 180)) * player.speed;
        player.z += Math.cos(dir * (Math.PI / 180)) * player.speed;
    }
}

let threeD = {
    FOV: 300,
    mx: 0,
    my: 0,
    mz: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    position: function (x, y, z) {
        threeD.mx = (z - player.z) * Math.sin(-player.hor * (Math.PI / 180)) + (x - player.x) * Math.cos(-player.hor * (Math.PI / 180));
        threeD.mz = (z - player.z) * Math.cos(-player.hor * (Math.PI / 180)) - (x - player.x) * Math.sin(-player.hor * (Math.PI / 180));
        threeD.my = (threeD.mz - player.z) * Math.sin(-player.ver * (Math.PI / 180)) + (y - player.y) * Math.cos(-player.ver * (Math.PI / 180));
        threeD.mz = (threeD.mz - player.z) * Math.cos(-player.ver * (Math.PI / 180)) - (y - player.y) * Math.sin(-player.ver * (Math.PI / 180));

        threeD.x = 2 * ((threeD.mx * (threeD.FOV / threeD.mz))) + canvas.width / 2;
        threeD.y = 2 * (-(threeD.my * (threeD.FOV / threeD.mz))) + canvas.height / 2;
    },

    lineTo: function (x, y, z) {
        threeD.position(x, y, z);
        ctx.lineTo(threeD.x, threeD.y);
    }
}
```

I've tried flipping everything in this script but I can't get it to work properly. I feel like it's going to be something obvious but I don't know.